# NodeJS module 'request' returns some symbols instead of html

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cheerio, requestjs

I am learning Nodejs, and try to do web scraping with node.js

I am using node module `request` and `cheerio`

but when I request the url it returns some symbol instead of the `html` body

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
request({
    url:"http://mangafox.me/manga/shingeki_no_kyojin/v00/c000/1.html"
},(err, res, body) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    
    else {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        console.log(body);
        }
});
```

output in command prompt

[image]

Can anyone please tell me
What is the problem here?

Thank You

Comment: What is in `res.headers['content-type']`?

Comment: `res.headers` is

`{ server: 'nginx/1.0.15',
  date: 'Wed, 10 Aug 2016 13:12:46 GMT',
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  connection: 'close',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=3600',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  expires: 'Wed, 10 Aug 2016 21:31:15 GMT',
  'content-encoding': 'gzip',
  vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
  'x-cache': 'HIT' }
`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the server is sending a compressed response, even though you aren't requesting a compressed response.

The easy fix is to just add `gzip: true` to your `request()` options, which will not only automatically decompress responses but will also send the appropriate `Accept-Encoding` header to the server.